# How to prevent database user deleting data from ALL tables by triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, triggers

Hi Experts
How I can prevent database user deleting any data in tables using triggers?
I want just Admin delete Data from tables

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any particular reason you want to use triggers?

You could simply remove the DELETE permission from the users you want to restrict. Have a look at the "Permissions" section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

**EDIT:** Since you say you do want to use triggers (but I really think you should reconsider) you can create a table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE Restricted_Users 
(
  user_name VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY_KEY -- Use a size appropriate to your requirements
)
```

Create `INSTEAD OF DELETE` triggers on *all* your tables (that's going to be a chore) which checks for the `USER_NAME()` in the `Restricted_Users` table and if they `EXIST` you can call `RAISERROR` to cause the transaction to be rolled back and display a message to the user.

Remember you will have to maintain these triggers on all new tables added to the database as well as maintaining the list of users in the `Restricted_Users` table whenever you add/remove users from the database.

It would be *a lot* simpler to use the permission system available in SQL Server (it's what it's designed for) using roles with appropriate permissions set for the tables. Then, when adding new users you only have to assign them to the appropriate role and the delete permissions are handled for you.

Comment: In which case you will have to set up a table of users you want to prevent deleting data. In the trigger lookup the `USER_NAME()` performing the delete to know if you should rollback the action.

Comment: @Nima Can you explain why you want to use a trigger? It is less efficient and less secure than just setting up the required permissions.

Comment: @Nima: If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later you can use the procedure `sys.dm_exec_connections` to get the `client_net_address` BUT this will only work if you are using TCP connections to your server (I think). Here's a link to the BOL page for the procedure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Umm take away that users permission?  If you don't want them doing something, 'disallow' them that right... thats why we have permissions.

Here are details on how to revoke permissions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186308.aspx

Comment: Correct answer but you linked to MySQL documentation, the question is tagged SQL Server :)

Comment: Oops.. corrected, I actually edited quickly after my post to add reference.